# Reading double c structures of Dll with Ctypes in Python

Tags: python, c, structure, ctypes

I'v done researched a lot about this problem.. But there's no where and I couldn't find it. I'm trying to call double c structure by calling c dll.

My question is, did i right way to declare "Class Structure" in python? I couldn't think that i'm right on my way. Because even though the Functions that I want to call from dll, It didn't come output anything.

[Visual C++/C]

I did try to C Syntax code,

```
typedef sturct {
    int nBoardNum;
    struct{
        char  pBoardName[16];
        int   nBoardID;
    }BOARDINDEX[8];
}AAPBOARDINFO, *PAAPBOARDINFO;

HANDLE AcapOpen(char* cpBoardName, int nBoardNo, int nCh)
```

[Python]

I changed Python Syntax like this.

```
import ctypes as c

class BOARDINDEX(c.Structure):
    _field_ = [("nBoardName", c.c_char_p * 16),("nBoardID", c.c_int)]

class AAPBOARDINFO(c.Structure):
    _field_ = [("nBoardNum", c.c_int), ("BOARDINDEX", BOARDINDEX * 8)]

AapLib2 = c.WinDLL("AapLib2.dll")

BoardName = ["ABC","FWD","HGW"]
BoardNo = 0
ch = 1

output = Open(BoardName, BoardNo, ch)

def Open(BoardName, BoardNo, ch)

    func = AapLib2.AcapOpen
    func.argtypes = [c.POINTER(BOARDINDEX),c.c_int, c.c_int]
    func.restype = c.c_int

    ref = BOARDINDEX()

    res = func(c.byref(ref.nBoardName),BoardNo, ch)
    return res
```

Nothing outcomes when call Open() function...

please consider my request and any answer would be great...

Comment: That C code you mention doesn't even compile. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to know, can be found in the [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are a couple of problems with the code:

1. Structure members are specified in the ***_fields_*** (**not** *_field_*) attribute
2. `char pBoardName[16]` maps to `ctypes.c_char * 16` (**not** *c_char_p*)
3. *HANDLE* should be mapped to *wintypes.HANDLE*
4. Function prototype differs between *C* and *Python*
5. Using globals like *AapLib2* is best to be be avoided, but I left them unchanged as they are outside the question scope

***#1.*** and ***#3.*** will generate ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*! Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for more details.

Here's a modified version of your code. Needless to say that I didn't actually test it, as I don't have the *.dll*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys
from ctypes import wintypes as wts


class BOARDINDEX(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("nBoardName", cts.c_char * 16),
        ("nBoardID", cts.c_int),
    ]


class AAPBOARDINFO(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("nBoardNum", cts.c_int),
        ("BOARDINDEX", BOARDINDEX * 8),
    ]


def open_board(board_name, board_no, ch):
    AcapOpen = aaplib2.AcapOpen
    AcapOpen.argtypes = (cts.c_char_p, cts.c_int, cts.c_int)
    AcapOpen.restype = wts.HANDLE
    ref = BOARDINDEX(board_name, board_no)  # Probably this line should be replaced by the 3 (commented) ones below (AcapGetBoardInfo prototype would have to be specified as well)
    #abi = AAPBOARDINFO()
    #AcapGetBoardInfo(cts.byref(abi))
    #ref = abi.BOARDINDEX[0]
    res = AcapOpen(ref.nBoardName, ref.nBoardID, ch)
    return res


def main(*argv):
    board_names = (
        "ABC",
        "FWD",
        "HGW",
    )
    board_no = 0
    ch = 1
    aaplib2 = cts.WinDLL("AapLib2.dll")
    output = open_board(board_names[0], board_no, ch)
    print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Let me know how this works out.

Comment: I did follow this way

def open_board(board_name, board_no, ch):
    ...
    abi = AAPBOARDINFO()
    AcapGetBoardInfo(ctypes.byref(abi))
    ref = abi.BOARDINDEX[0]
    ...
And it works! SO appreciate it